# The cookie is deleted when the browser is closed

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this cookie to store users previous selection from a menu. But I want keep this cookie stored in the browser even if the user closes the browser. This code perfectly works on IE but when I close Chrome and Firefox, the cookie getting deleted. Can anyone provide me solution for this.

```
function setCookie(NameOfCookie, value, expiredays) {
    var ExpireDate = new Date();
    document.cookie = NameOfCookie + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + ExpireDate.toGMTString());
}

function delCookie (NameOfCookie) {
  if (getCookie(NameOfCookie)) {
    document.cookie = NameOfCookie + "=" + "; expires=Thu, 17-Jul-24 00:00:01 GMT";
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you call this code ? If you don't pass expiredays, then you explicitly require an immediate expireation.

Comment: i'm calling the function like this onClick="setCookie('redirectcountry', 'CA')"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you call the function with

```
setCookie('redirectcountry', 'CA')
```

then you set the expiry date to `new Date()`, that is "right now". So it's normal behavior to have the cookie be immediately deleted.

Simple solution : call it as

```
setCookie('redirectcountry', 'CA', true)
```

Comment: so what do you suggest ?

Comment: @user3689990 don't set an expiry date

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your browsers settings? In Firefox this is option called 'Keep until' with value 'I close Firefox' (Privacy tab).

Comment: Yes. I checked. I set to Firefox will to Remember history. Now Firefox  keeps the cookie even if the browser is closed. How do I this in Chrome

Comment: Settings, Privacy, Content settings and then select "allow local data to be set". Afaik this option should be set by default...